# How to create nested object in MongoDB schema

Tags: mongoose, database, nosql

I currently have the following schema for a MongoDB document which is supposed to save user data:

```
var userSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {type: String, unique : true},
  password: {type: String},
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String,
  sketches: 
              [ 
                {name: String, 
                 sketch: Array}
              ]
```

The sketches attribute needs to be an array objects where each object associates the name of a sketch and an array which holds the sketch data. For some reason, the schema ends up being created as the following:

```
{
    "__v" : 1,
    "_id" : ObjectId("57c4d7693aa85cea2acf4d4d"),
    "firstname" : "test",
    "lastname" : "name",
    "password" : "password123",
    "sketches" : [ 
        {
            "sketch" : []
        }
    ],
    "username" : "testname"
}
```

I'm not exactly sure the correct format for creating nested objects in MongoDB but I was assuming that it would be the same as it would for JSON. How should the schema be structured to yield an array of objects.

### EDIT:

**web service to insert into document from PUT request:**

```
app.route("/addSketch/:username").put(function(req, res, next) {
  var user_name = req.params.username;
  User.findOne({username:user_name},function(err,foundObject){
    if(err){
      console.log("error");
      res.status(500).send();
    }
    else{
      if(!foundObject){
        res.status(404).send();
      }
      else{
        
        if(req.body.strokes && req.body.sketchName){
          var sketchObj = [];
          sketchObj[req.body.sketchName] = req.body.strokes;
          foundObject.sketches.push(req.body.sketchData);
        }
        foundObject.save(function(err,updatedObject){
          if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send();
          }
          else{
            res.send(updatedObject);
          }
        });
      }
    }

  });


  console.log('saving on server');
   var form = formidable.IncomingForm();

   console.log(form);
   console.log('the type of the request received is', (typeof req));

  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      res.writeHead(200, {"content-type": "text/plain"});
      res.write('received upload:\n\n');
    var name = fields.name;
    var newSketch = new SavedSketch();
      newSketch.name = name;
      newSketch.sketchData =  fields.value;
      newSketch.save(function(err,savedObject){
        if(err){
               console.log(err);
               res.status(500).json({status:'failure'})
            }
            else{
              console.log("ID: " + fields.value.id + " strokeData:" + fields.value.strokes);
               res.json({status: 'success'});
            } 
      });

         res.end();
  });
  });
```

Comment: How are you inserting the documents in your Mongoose code, can you show that part as well?

Comment: @chridam I just updated the post. I was also thinking of making the sketches array a subdocument of the User document but I wasn't sure the best way to go about doing that exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Schema**

```
var userSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {type: String, unique : true},
  password: {type: String},
  firstname:{type: String},
  lastname: {type: String},
  sketches: [
    {
      name: String,
      sketch : {type : Array}
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: That seems like it works, I ended up creating a sub document for sketches instead. I'll post another answer with what I did.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up creating a sub document for sketches and making that a child of the User Schema:

```
var sketchSchema =  mongoose.Schema({ name: String, sketchData : Array
  });
var SavedSketch = mongoose.model('Sketch', sketchSchema);
// });


var userSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {type: String, unique : true},
  password: {type: String},
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String,

  sketches:[sketchSchema]


var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Comment: What is the difference between declaration: `password: {type: String}` vs `firstname: String` ?.

Comment: @Sunny `{type : String}` is equal `: String`. The first pattern, we can add more option like `password: {type: String, unique: true, requried: true }`.